# Namespace issue in flutter after update to Gradle to 8.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I recently update Gradle "com.android.tools.build:gradle" version to 8.0.0 in my flutter project after that namespace issue started, So i change my build.gradle accordingly but it has not affect always throw error **namespace not specified** when build android project.

-- sorry for bad english--

I tried to add namespace in build.gradle(app) and remove package from AndroidManifest file as suggested and also after updating android studio not able to open AGP upgrade assistant in android so i am not able to resolve namespace error.

Please help if any one know, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your errors from the logcat or the console ? Can you also provide you build.gradle files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue i faced. Here is how i solved this issue.

1. you need to update Kotlin versions.

Ex : My updated version numbers below.

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

2. update gradle wrapper

   ```
    distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
   ```
3. change ext kotlin version

   ```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
   ```

Change these 3 and gradle sync it will fix this issue

Comment: another day, another 2 hours spent following android studio prompts and getting myself in trouble then manually undoing the works of AGP upgrade assistant. Thanks mate.

Comment: I did.. that's me.